# Is there any class in .Net 4.0 that be able to create random string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, .net-4.0, random

I want to create a random string (about 20 characters length). Is there any built-in class in .net that able to create random string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Path.GetRandomFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx)

> The GetRandomFileName method returns a cryptographically strong,
>   random string that can be used as either a folder name or a file name.
>   Unlike GetTempFileName, GetRandomFileName does not create a file. When
>   the security of your file system is paramount, this method should be
>   used instead of GetTempFileName.

Comment: He wanted 20 chars, and this is only 11 and no way to change the number of chars. He can of course run it twice, and strip away the two dots for a grand total of 20 chars ;)

Comment: See my answer for a function that loops calls to GetRandomFileName to obtain a random string of any length. It's pretty efficient, not that you'd ever need 100 one-million-character random strings , but it can generate them in 47 seconds on my Core2 Duo.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a Guid then convert it to a string.

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
```

This will give you a random string with the length 36, but you could then just trim this down to 20.

Comment: It's worth reading thru how GUIDs are generated -- taking portions of a GUID are not random: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx

Comment: Yeah this is something to consider if "about 20 characters" is going to be required or they can manage with 36 :P

Answer (score 3):

Use `Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace('-', default(Char)).Substring(0, 20)`

Comment: `ToString()` on the GUID allows for a format specifier as described in the [**GUID.ToString() MSDN Documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx). One of them being `ToString("N")` which removes the dashes. No need to call `Replace()`.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
string myString = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try [TestApi](http://testapi.codeplex.com/), more specifically the [Text String Generation API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2010/04/14/9995847.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Path.GetRandomFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) will create you a random file name - think it's only 11 chars long though.

Answer (score 0):

Generating Random Strings in .NET

http://www.keyvan.ms/generating-random-strings-in-net

Article covers GUID, Random Numbers and RNGCryptoServiceProvider methods to generate random string

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I wrote that uses GetRandomFileName() to get a random string of any length.

```
''' <summary>
''' Obtain a random string of any length.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="length">Desired length of string.</param>
''' <returns></returns>
''' <remarks></remarks>
Public Shared Function GetRandomString(ByVal length As Integer) As String        
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder(length)
    While (sb.Length < length)
        ' GetRandomFileName returns a "cryptographically strong" random filename ex: "bfdbn2af.sxq"
        sb.Append(IO.Path.GetRandomFileName().Replace(".", ""))
    End While
    ' strip the excess characters
    sb.Remove(length - 1, sb.Length - length)
    Return sb.ToString()
End Function
```